# Calculating R2 Score and RMSE using K-Fold Cross Validation

Tags: python, machine-learning

In the below mentioned code, I am performing a `Non-Linear Regression` using `Random Forest Regressor`.

I am taking Train, Test, Split to Evaluate my Model using R2 Score, RMSE and MAPE. Now, I want to Evaluate my Model using K-Fold Cross Validation which I have divided into 4 Splits. Can you please help me out as to how shall I calculate the Mean R2 Score, RMSE and MAPE of the 4 Splits which I have done as part of the K-Fold Cross Validation?

```
# STEP 1: IMPORTING THE REQUIRED LIBRARIES AND MODULES
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_percentage_error
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE, SelectFromModel
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn import model_selection
import math

# STEP 2: READING THE DATA AND PERFORMING BASIC DATA CHECKS
path = "C:/AKHIL/OTHER/MISSION_INTERNSHIP/Space4Good/DATA_FOR_MODELING_2.xlsx"
sheet_1 = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name='Model Development')
sheet_2 = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name='Validation Data')
x_validation = sheet_2.drop(['ID'], axis=1).values
print("STATISTICAL DESCRIPTION:")
print(sheet_1.describe(), "\n")

# STEP 3: CREATING ARRAYS FOR THE FEATURES AND THE RESPONSE VARIABLE
target_column = ['y', 'ID']
predictors = list(set(list(sheet_1.columns)) - set(target_column))

# STEP 4: PERFORMING NORMALIZATION VIA SCALING OF THE PREDICTORS BETWEEN 0 AND 1
scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
names = sheet_1[predictors].columns
d = scaler.fit_transform(sheet_1[predictors])
sheet_1[predictors] = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=names)
print("STATISTICAL DESCRIPTION AFTER NORMALIZATION:")
print(sheet_1.describe())

# STEP 5: CREATING TRAINING AND TEST DATASETS
X = sheet_1[predictors]  # ALL THESE VALUES ARE NORMALIZED
y = sheet_1['y']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)

# STEP 6: BUILD, PREDICT AND EVALUATE THE MODELS USING DECISION TREE ALGORITHM
dtree = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=500, oob_score=True, random_state=0)
print(dtree.fit(X_train, y_train))
pred_test_tree = dtree.predict(X_test)
print("EVALUATION ON TEST SET:", "\n")
print("RMSE:", np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, pred_test_tree)))
print("R2 SCORE:", r2_score(y_test, pred_test_tree))
print("MAPE:", mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_test, pred_test_tree), "\n")

# STEP 7: K-FOLD CROSS VALIDATION
kf = KFold(n_splits=4)

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For a question like this, you should really post a minimal reproducible example: the dataset are known only to you so why don't you try to make an abstraction of the problem?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Referring [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html)

```
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
 X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
 y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
 dtree.fit(X_train, y_train)
 pred_test_tree= dtree.predict(X_test)
 print("RMSE:", np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, pred_test_tree)))
 print("R2 SCORE:", r2_score(y_test, pred_test_tree))
 print("MAPE:", mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_test, pred_test_tree), "\n")
```

(I have not tested the code)

Comment: That's exactly what I have already done in the code. My concern was that i am not able to understand as to how to calculate RMSE, R2 Score and MAPE using K-Fold Cross Validation.